# Date of creation is older than previous day until 6am

Tags: c#, datetime

I have app where is datagridview with data from sql database - and a want to modify every row. I have button for this and if i will click there will appear new Form and there I can modify every record, but I want to that user can edit only records up to the previous day until 6 am , later records user cannot modify.

```
if (DateTime.Parse(labelDate.Text) < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2))
{

      labelNotice.Text = "Cannot modify records older than 2 days"
      button1.Enabled = false;

 }
```

My problem is that i dont know how to make date-time limit for this. I have labelDate where I have date of creation and I need to compare with actual date and time and I need to app will say to user that if labelDate is older than previous day until 6am you cannot modify nothing. Now I have only compare date of creation and if its 2 days older button1 will be disabled.

But I need date and time to compare.

Comment: _DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2).AddHours(6)_  DateTime.Today is today without time (or better is today at midnight)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eNS5ix <= I always found it easier to read when comparing against a `TimeSpan`.